# Android APK expansions: подход к предоставлению контента

Tags: android, android-sdk, apk

После завершения первоначальных оценок объема работы и прикидок по архитектуре моего следующего offline-приложения, 
я думаю об одноразовой, массивной "content delivery" с помощью механизма APK expansion files вместе с первым запуском.

***Вот некоторые предварительные условия:***

- 99% поставленного pre-defined контента из расширения (по приблизительной оценке ~0,3gb для начала) 
  будет графическим контентом (png, img и т.д.). Таким образом, он будет состоять из большого количества ~700kb "кусков", заключенных в директории.
- Что касается структурирования и обработки уже доставленного контента (пути хранения, имена и теги в случае графического содержимого), 
  здесь я бы предпочел использовать библиотеку, такую ​​как [requery](https://github.com/requery/requery), с которой я хорошо знаком для агрегирования результатов поиска в приложении, 
  перевода и хранения данных/метаданных в SQL и связывания нескольких слоев данных.
- Как уже упоминалось, приложение будет работать в автономном режиме (разве что кроме auth/profile-операций, поддерживаемых Firebase): 
  в настоящий момент имеется больше "за", нежели "против" сделать его автономным.
- Я никогда не делал ничего подобного в мобильной разработке.

Предметная тема приложения предоставляет прекрасную(по крайней мере, я так думаю) возможность иметь структурированное 
дерево пакетов с хорошо очерченной иерархией и графическим содержимым внутри каждого последнего дочернего пакета.
То, о чем я пишу, можно примерно понять, глядя на эту схему(*взял фиктивные темы из реальной жизни*):

````
```
    root_
        ├── _food
        |   ├── _healthy
        |   |   ├── _vegetables
        |   |   |   ├── content_description.png
        |   |   |   └── content_description.png
        |   |   └── _fruits
        |   |       ├── content_description.png
        |   |       └── content_description.png
        |   └── _dangerous
        |       └── _lard
        |           ├── content_description.png
        |           └── content_description.png
        ├── _sports
        |   ├── _gym
        |   |   ├── _weight_gain
        |   |   |   ├── content_description.png
        |   |   |   └── content_description.png
        |   |   └── _power_gain
        |   |       ├── content_description.png
        |   |       └── content_description.png
        |   └── _cardio
        |       └── _running
        |           ├── content_description.png
        |           └── content_description.png
        └── _lifestyle
            └── _fitness_bracelets
                ├── content_description.png
                └── content_description.png

```
````

---

***Почему я считаю, что этот подход имеет шансы на жизнь:***

- Поскольку большая часть контента на самом деле будет представлять из себя большое кол-во картинок, одним из основных преимуществ этого подхода для меня является 
  способность структурировать этот зоопарк в пакеты с соответствующим названием  по предметам/подзаголовкам и так далее.
  Другими словами, "малой кровью" сделать дерево пакетов с тем количеством узлов, которое мне понадобится в будущем.
- Другим преимуществом для меня является то, что в большинстве случаев процесс подготовки контента будет выполняться 
  полностью независимо от процесса разработки приложения и на любом устройстве с совместимой файловой системой: локальная машина, рабочая машина, возможно даже планшет и т.д.
- Я не могу опустить и эти факторы, поскольку они для меня сейчас важны: никаких кастомных/firebase'овских 
  бэкэндов и хранилищ; нет необходимости разрабатывать API; никаких web-запросов;  никаких дополнительных расходов на данный момент.

---

Прежде чем идти дальше, очень хочется услышать людей, имеющих опыт работы с APK expansions и опытных людей в целом: <strike>это хорошая идея вообще?</strike> 
что может быть ближайшей альтернативой этому подходу с упомянутыми предпосылками? Каковы преимущества и недостатки такого вот одноразового 
(максимум - совершаемого после каждой установки или обновления) рекурсивного парсинга дерева 
пакетов загруженного расширения и сохранения в SQL путей / файлов его содержимого?

Буду благодарен за любые конструктивные мысли.